# What's the max number of discipline dots a vampire should have at a given age?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

I'm currently putting together a VTM forum rpg over on zetaboards on the premise that some vampires *did* survive Gehenna and are trying to pick up the pieces with most of their kind having been wiped out and odd new bloodlines emerging. The game will have Kindred characters of the new bloodlines ranging in age (as vampires) from 1-9 years, and 'original' Kindred characters (vampires that were embraced prior to and survived Gehenna). I'm setting maximum age of original Kindred characters at no older than 250, but my question is...what would be a fair guideline as to how many dots per discipline these characters can have? Like, for example, someone wants to play a 50 year old Brujah, another a 200 year old Ventrue. Would a maximum limit of 3 dots in a given discipline for a character 100 years or less, maximum of 4 per discipline for 200 years or more be fair?

I'm basing the premise on a combination of the Nightshade and Wormwood scenarios. Mainly vampires were dying from the Withering, and the surviving Antediluvians gathered in the valley of Hinom (as per Nightshade) and when they died, the Withering stopped- so the oldest and most powerful vampires died, and the surviving `originals' are the relatively younger ones. The oldest confirmed Kindred survivor is Beckett (because I'm biased and he was always my favorite character XD ). I'm putting my own spin because when the Antes (presumably Caine too) died, the original curse was altered a bit.

Answer (score 7):

Page 79 of V20 clearly states the numbers that you are looking for in a text box called "Advancing New Characters":

> **Advancing New Characters**
>
> Storytellers may choose to allow players to create more experienced and knowledgeable characters. Indeed, players of Vampire: The Masquerade 20th Anniversary Edition may prefer an “ancilla game” or an all-elders chronicle instead. In this case, we recommend first building a neonate character and then granting players a number of experience points that allows them to increase their characters’ Traits to levels suitable to the chronicle and the age of their vampires.
>   **As a basic rule of thumb, “idle” Kindred should have a number of Discipline dots equal to the square root of her age.** **Remember that players’ characters are rarely “idle” like Storyteller characters, so they’ll rapidly outpace this guideline.** That’s fine; they’re out there in the world, having exciting encounters and earning more experience than passive Storyteller characters. Remember that the cost for raising a Trait which is already advanced can be very expensive.
>   See p. 124 for more information on spending experience points.
>
> Kindred Age Category: Experience Points
>
> Neonate: 0-35
>
> Ancilla: 75-220
>
> Elder: 250-600
>
> Methuselahs: 1000+

I would think of this "rule of thumb" as just a limit of how many disciplines may be bought with XP. For example, if a typical Camarilla fledgling generates with 3 disciplines (up to 5), let's say that he has spent 80 years as an "idle" vampire and has 150 bonus XP. He could theoretically buy a lot of discipline points with that! But is limited to a square root of his age, which is ~9. And he may only buy up to 6, as he already has 3 that he got during generation.

If the Storyteller assumes that the character was not "idle" but rather as active as typical *player* character during that time, the Storyteller is free do provide bonus XP and no limit on discipline dots.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're trying to place a focus on younger vampires, particularly through the development of new bloodlines post-Gehenna. Given that, your guidelines look pretty "fair" -- making level-5 and above disciplines rare will certainly keep your vampires feeling young. What you might want to consider is whether you have the same limits for *out-of-clan* disciplines. Otherwise, you'll find yourself with Kindred with threes and fours in all of the common 8. I might allow in-clans to 5 and out-of-clans to 3 for those >100, and 4 and 2 for those below.

Answer (score 0):

The only ***hard*** rule on experience to discipline is generation based i quote from [white wolf wikia](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Discipline_(VTM))

> Cainites of seventh or lower generation may learn Advanced Disciplines of six to ten dots, with the maximum rating of a Discipline restricted to 13 minus their generation. At such levels the potency of Discipline powers increase greatly, and characters no longer must follow a uniform progression but can choose from a variety of powers available at any one level or even invent their own powers that suit their tactics. Advanced Disciplines provide elders a great advantage over higher generation Cainites, but also lure younger vampires to commit diablerie.

Now this is obviously not a per-se to age translation, but i'm pretty sure restrictions don't get harder than this.